# Why doesn't unobtrusive validation work until after an AJAX post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have an MVC3 project wherein I'd like to use custom validation attributes for client- and server-side processing.  I've followed the steps found at http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/custom-unobtrusive-jquery-validation-with-data-annotations-in-mvc-3/.  That was a great tutorial and it actually works perfectly.

The only problem I'm having is that my validations don't seem to trigger until **after** the form has been submitted.  I have client- and server-side validation.  The server-side validation is a combination of validation attributes and custom validation (sometimes I have to check the input value against something in the database, for example).  The first time I click the Save button on my form (using Ajax.BeginForm) the post happens to the server, the server-side validation kicks in and returns validation messages because the input is invalid.  If I leave the form inputs exactly as they are and I click the Save button again, the client-side validation works properly and prevents the post from happening.

What could be causing the client-side validation to be skipped until after the form is posted?

My custom validation attribute:

```
    public class RequiredIfContainsAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        private RequiredAttribute _innerAttribute = new RequiredAttribute();

        public string DependentProperty { get; set; }
        public string ComparisonValue { get; set; }

        public RequiredIfContainsAttribute(string dependentProperty, string comparisonValue)
        {
            DependentProperty = dependentProperty;
            ComparisonValue = comparisonValue;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            // get a reference to the property this validation depends upon
            var containerType = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
            var field = containerType.GetProperty(DependentProperty);

            if (field != null)
            {
                // get the value of the dependent property
                var dependentValue = field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

                // this validation only works if the comparison field is a string
                if (dependentValue.GetType() != typeof(string))
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }

                var dependentString = (string) dependentValue;

                // check whether the string to check contains the comparison value
                if (dependentString.Contains(ComparisonValue))
                {
                    // if the string to check contains the comparison value, the attribute becomes required and must now be validated
                    if (!_innerAttribute.IsValid(value))
                    {
                        // validation failed - return an error
                        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage, new[] {validationContext.MemberName});
                    }
                }
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata,
                                                                           ControllerContext context)
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
                {
                    ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
                    ValidationType = "requiredifcontains"
                };

            var depProp = BuildDependentPropertyId(metadata, context as ViewContext);

            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("dependentproperty", depProp);
            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("comparisonvalue", ComparisonValue);

            yield return rule;
        }

        private string BuildDependentPropertyId(ModelMetadata metadata, ViewContext viewContext)
        {
            string depProp = viewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(DependentProperty);

            var thisField = metadata.PropertyName + "_";
            if (depProp.StartsWith(thisField))
            {
                // strip it off again
                depProp = depProp.Substring(thisField.Length);
            }

            return depProp;
        }
    }
```

My model attribute:

```
    [RequiredIfContains("FirstName", "Mickey", ErrorMessage = "The date of birth is required when the first name is Mickey")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

My custom js to add the validators:

```
$.validator.addMethod('requiredifcontains',
function (value, element, parameters) {
    console.log("requiredifcontains starting");
    var id = '#' + parameters['dependentproperty'];

    // get the target value (as a string, 
    // as that's what actual value will be)
    var comparisonvalue = parameters['comparisonvalue'];
    comparisonvalue =
      (comparisonvalue == null ? '' : comparisonvalue).toString();

    // get the actual value of the target control
    // note - this probably needs to cater for more 
    // control types, e.g. radios
    var control = $(id);
    var inputValue = 'empty';
    if (control.is('input:text')) {
        inputValue = control.text();
    } else if (control.is('select')) {
        inputValue = $(id + " option:selected").text();
    }

    // if the input control wasn't found (possibly because the type wasn't checked for) then we can't compare so just return true
    if (inputValue == 'empty') {
        return true;
    }

    // if the condition is true, reuse the existing 
    // required field validator functionality
    console.log("requiredifcontains performing underlying validation");
    if (inputValue.indexOf(comparisonvalue) > -1)
        return $.validator.methods.required.call(
          this, value, element, parameters);

    console.log("requiredifcontains returning true");
    return true;
}
);

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
'requiredifcontains',
['dependentproperty', 'comparisonvalue'],
function (options) {
    options.rules['requiredifcontains'] = {
        dependentproperty: options.params['dependentproperty'],
        targetvalue: options.params['comparisonvalue']
    };
    options.messages['requiredifcontains'] = options.message;
});
```

A contrived view that is nearly identical to the one that is failing:

```
@{
var options = new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        UpdateTargetId = "personalInfoDiv",
        OnSuccess = "FormSubmitSuccess()"
    };
}

<div id="personalInfoDiv">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PersonalInformationDetail", "PersonalInformation", null, options, new {@style = "height:100%", @id = "PersonalInformationForm"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <div style="float:left; position:relative;">
        <input type="button" value="Save" style="width:125px;" id="Save" onclick="saveClick(this)" />
    </div>
}
</div>
```

The javascript for the Save click and the on success method:

```
function saveClick(e) {
var firstName = $("#FirstName").val();
var result = true;
if (firstName == '') {
    result = confirm("First name is not required but is recommended.  Choose OK to save anyway or CANCEL to add a first name.");
}

if (result) {
    $("#PersonalInformationForm").submit();
}
}

function FormSubmitSuccess(result) {
// do some stuff after the form submits
}
```

I've been searching for this for some time and most of the solutions I've found are solutions for the opposite of my problem.  I've logged the results of form.validate() and I see that the first time I click Save there are no errors, but the second time (after the post) the errors are there.

This is probably something simple that I'm missing, but I have no idea what else to try here and I'm running out of time.

This is my first post here so if I've neglected to include something pertinent, please just let me know and I can update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure why it is working the second time around, for the client-side validation to work you will want to prevent the form being submitted by returning false or doing an e.preventDefault() in the `saveClick()` method.

Comment: Actually, I don't think I need to prevent the default because my Save button is actually an <input type="button" instead of <input type="submit".  Do you agree?

Comment: You are correct. After looking at the question again I think I see what may be happening, MVC3 is going to try to submit the form to the server for validation using Ajax.BeginForm. I believe if you use HTML.BeginForm then the jQuery validator will have a chance to kick in and stop the form submitting traditionally. This may be the reason it is working the second time around, since it probably knows not to attempt its own Ajax POST. Let me know if that works and I will post a new answer.